# Como alterar a propriedade TranslationX de um elemento através do x:Name?

Tags: xamarin, binding

Tenho um XAML com a seguinte estrutura:

```html
<swipeview:SwipeCollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" x:Name="swipeListView">

  <swipeview:SwipeCollectionView.ItemTemplate>

    <DataTemplate>
      <material:MaterialCard Elevation="1" x:Name="Card" Padding="1" BackgroundColor="White" WidthRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference swipeListView}, Path=Width}" CornerRadius="4" Margin="5,5,5,5">

        <StackLayout>

          <StackLayout Padding="15">
            <Button IsVisible="True" Text="SwipeRight" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Clicked="SwipeClick" CommandParameter="{Reference Name=loopedElement}" />


          </StackLayout>

          <swipeview:SwipeItemView x:Name="loopedElement" BoundItem="{Binding .}" ChangeOpacity="True" IsVisible="True" SwipeRightCompleted="SwipeRightCompleted" SwipeLeftCompleted="SwipeLeftCompleted">

            <!--Swipe Main Content -->
            <swipeview:SwipeItemView.MainContent>
              <StackLayout>
                <material:MaterialCard Elevation="1" Padding="2" BorderColor="Gray" CornerRadius="4" x:Name="mcard" >

                  (...)
```

No entanto, ***mcard*** não aparece no code behind.

A intenção é que quando o botão for clicado, a propriedade TranslationX do elemento MaterialCard seja alterada.

Consigo acessar swipeListView no code behind mas não mcard.

Estou travado nisso há dias. Agradeço desde já a todos que puderem ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Voce não vai conseguir pegar o x:name porque ele está dentro de um ItemTemplate/DataTemplate

Voce vai ter que pegar o objeto pai do mcard e ir buscando o Chidren[indice] até encontrar o item que você quer.

tente algo semelhante a isso:

```
(VisualContainer)swipeListView.GetType().GetProperty("VisualContainer", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(swipeListView).Children[indice]...;
```

e partir do resultado disso, você pega o Children

ou com uma ação, voce pega o objeto da ação, acessa o Parent e depois busque o Children

```
 private void EnviarPara(object sender, SwitchStateChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var switched = (SfSwitch)sender;
            StackLayout stPai = (StackLayout)switched.Parent;
            
            if (((Label)stPai.Children[0]).Text != "Todos"){
                  return true; 
            }
```